# Instance proxy with monkey-patched method

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance, monkeypatching, proxy-pattern

I need a way to create a "proxy" to an instance with monkey-patched methods/fields.

- I don't want to use a context manager and/or directly modify the instance.
- I cannot use inheritance - I'm given an instance, that's it.

**Do you know of any package that makes it possible?**

Here's my very rough attempt showing the functionality I need:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Foo init')

    def m1(self):
        print("Foo - m1")
        self.m2()

    def m2(self):
        print("Foo - m2")
        self.m3()

    # I want to alter the behavior of this method in a single (isolated) instance!
    def m3(self):
        print("Foo - m3")


class MyPatchingProxy:
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            return getattr(self.wrapped.__class__, item).__get__(self, self.__class__) # something with a descriptor
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.wrapped, item) # something else

    def m3(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Wrapped M3. Now comes the original...")
        self.wrapped.m3(*args, **kwargs)
        print("... and the wrapper continues.")



my_foo = Foo()
# Foo init
my_foo.m1()
# Foo - m1
# Foo - m2
# Foo - m3

print('-'*80)

wrapped_foo = MyPatchingProxy(my_foo)
wrapped_foo.m1()
# Foo - m1
# Foo - m2
# Wrapped M3. Now comes the original...
# Foo - m3
# ... and the wrapper continues.

print('-'*80)

print("And the original my_foo works as before")
my_foo.m1()
# Foo - m1
# Foo - m2
# Foo - m3
```

Comment: your code snippet works well to me, why bother to use a package?

Comment: this lib may be fit: http://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrappers.html

Comment: Yes, I've tried `wrapt`, but I have no idea how to achieve the desired result using that lib. I've ended up patching the method directly in the instance, not in the proxy - but it is not what I want.

Comment: > why bother to use a package
Because someone could have written tests, debugged and fixed many corner cases. The above snipped is, by no means, bullet proof ;)

Comment: I've managed to write an example with `wrapt` lib, any feedback?

Comment: @georgexsh Yes, your example is wrong. It modifies the original instance. `proxy.m1()` and `my_foo.m1()` both calls the `m3` wrapper. Please notice in my example: "the original my_foo works as before".

Comment: I see it is impossible with `wrapt`, there no mechanism to bound function from `Foo` with the proxy instance.